# Recursive query in PostgreSQL to create a Menu tree

Tags: postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

How to create a json of a hierarchical structure in SQL with PostgreSQL 12?
I need to create a menu like the image below, this menu is already working, but the solution I am using is not very optimized and has a great overhead because I am making many accesses to the database in PHP code with foreach and recursion.
I would like a solution to access the database only once and get the JSON tree ready.

I made a SQL code that is not working very well because it is not merging menu items from the same parent

[image]

My current test implementation in SQL is failing, because it is repeating "Jubarte", it is not merging the items of "Jubarte":

```sql
CREATE TABLE menus
(
  id          bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id integer   NOT NULL,
  "idPai"   bigint,
  label        text,
  rota text
);

INSERT INTO menus(customer_id, "idPai", label, rota) VALUES
(1,NULL,'Jubarte', ''),
(2,1,'Cadastros', ''),
(3,NULL,'Ciente', ''),
(4,1,'Autorizações', ''),
(5,4,'Menus', ''),
(6,2,'Organograma', ''),
(7,1,'Minha Conta', '');

WITH RECURSIVE menus_tree("id", "customer_id", "idPai", "label", "rota", "children") AS (
  -- tree leaves (no matching children)
  (SELECT c.*, json '[]'
  FROM menus c
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM menus AS hypothetic_child WHERE hypothetic_child."idPai" = c.id)   
   )
  UNION ALL
  -- pozs's awesome "little hack"
  SELECT (parent).*, json_agg(child) AS "children"
  FROM (
    SELECT parent, child
    FROM menus_tree AS child
    JOIN menus parent ON parent.id = child."idPai"
  ) branch
  GROUP BY branch.parent
)
SELECT jsonb_pretty(json_agg(t)::jsonb)
FROM menus_tree t
LEFT JOIN menus AS hypothetic_parent ON(hypothetic_parent.id = t."idPai")
WHERE hypothetic_parent.id IS NULL;
```

Result:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "rota": "",
        "idPai": null,
        "label": "Ciente",
        "children": [
        ],
        "customer_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "rota": "",
        "idPai": null,
        "label": "Jubarte",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "rota": "",
                "idPai": 1,
                "label": "Minha Conta",
                "children": [
                ],
                "customer_id": 7
            }
        ],
        "customer_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "rota": "",
        "idPai": null,
        "label": "Jubarte",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "rota": "",
                "idPai": 1,
                "label": "Cadastros",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "rota": "",
                        "idPai": 2,
                        "label": "Organograma",
                        "children": [
                        ],
                        "customer_id": 6
                    }
                ],
                "customer_id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "rota": "",
                "idPai": 1,
                "label": "Autorizações",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "rota": "",
                        "idPai": 4,
                        "label": "Menus",
                        "children": [
                        ],
                        "customer_id": 5
                    }
                ],
                "customer_id": 4
            }
        ],
        "customer_id": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution, I don’t know if it’s the best but it’s working like this, if someone has a better idea, please can suggest

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE location_with_level AS (
    (
        SELECT
            menus.*,
            0 AS level 
        FROM
            menus,
            usuarios u, permissoes P -- <== part to filter by user permissions
            
        WHERE
            "idPai" IS NULL 
            -- part to filter by user permissions       
            AND u."idPerfil" = P."idPerfil" 
            AND u."idSistema" = P."idSistema" 
            AND P."idMenu" = menus."id" 
            AND u."idPessoa" = 2 
            AND menus."ativo" = 't'
            
        ) UNION ALL
        (
        SELECT
            child.*,
            parent.level + 1 
        FROM
            usuarios u, permissoes P, -- <== part to filter by user permissions
            menus child 
            JOIN location_with_level parent ON parent.ID = child."idPai" 
            -- part to filter by user permissions           
        WHERE
            u."idPerfil" = P."idPerfil" 
            AND u."idSistema" = P."idSistema" 
            AND P."idMenu" = child."id" 
            AND u."idPessoa" = 2 
            AND child."ativo" = 't'             
        ) 
    ),
    -- pega o nivel
    maxlvl AS ( SELECT MAX ( level ) maxlvl FROM location_with_level ),
    -- generates the JSON of the menu items for each system module
    c_tree AS (
        ( 
        SELECT location_with_level.*, NULL::JSONB nodes FROM location_with_level, maxlvl WHERE level = maxlvl ) 
        
        UNION
        (
            (
            SELECT
                ( branch_parent ).*,
                jsonb_agg ( branch_child order by (branch_child->>'ordem')::numeric) 
            FROM
                (
                SELECT
                    branch_parent,
                    to_jsonb ( branch_child )  /*- 'level' - 'idPai' - 'id'*/ AS branch_child 
                FROM
                    location_with_level branch_parent
                    JOIN c_tree branch_child ON branch_child."idPai" = branch_parent.ID                 
                    
                ) branch 
            GROUP BY
                branch.branch_parent 
            ) UNION
            (
            SELECT C
                .*,
                NULL :: JSONB 
            FROM
                location_with_level C 
            WHERE
                NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM location_with_level hypothetical_child WHERE hypothetical_child."idPai" = C.ID ) 
            ) 
        
        ) 
    ) 
SELECT array_to_json(
           array_agg(
             row_to_json(c_tree)::JSONB /*- 'level' - 'idPai' - 'id'*/ order by sistemas.ordem
           )
         )::JSONB
        AS tree             
  FROM c_tree
    JOIN sistemas on c_tree."idSistema" = sistemas.id
  WHERE level=0
```